# Method in service is undefined when executing but not when logging to console

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 Service classes

UserClass

```
import axios from "axios";
export default class {
 constructor(){
   this.http= axios.create({baseURL:"/api/users/"});
 }
 getUser(userId){
  return this.http(userId);
 }
}
```

BusinessClass

```
import axios from "axios";
import AppState from "../utils/appState";
export default class {
 constructor(){
   this.http= axios.create({baseURL:"/api/business/"});
   this.appState = new AppState();
 }

 async getAllBusiness(){
   try{
    let result =await this.http("all");
    this.appState.save('all_business', result.data);
   }catch(ex){
    console.log("AllBusiness",ex);
   }
   return;
 }
}
```

When I import and create an instance of these in my vue component first one has all it's methods. But the second one loses it's methods in code.

When I put a debug point and log it, it will get logged as method. But when I execute it, it will log an error.

```
 //before export default
 import UserService from "../Services/UserService";
 import BusinessService from "../Services/BusinessService";
 //inside export default
 async created(){
   this.$UserService = new UserService();
   this.$BusinessService = new BusinessService();
   let result = await this.$UserService.getUser(this.id); //=> this one works
   await this.$BusinessService.getAllBusiness(); //=>this one logs  this.$BusinessService.getAllBusiness is not a function
 }
```

I also tried these two ways to define the method

```
 getAllBusiness(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
     this.http("all")
     .then((result)=>{
        this.appState.save('all_business', result.data);
        resolve()
      });
     .catch(()=>{reject()});
   });//also tried with bind(this)
 }

 getAllBusiness=()=>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
     this.http("all")
     .then((result)=>{
        this.appState.save('all_business', result.data);
        resolve()
      });
     .catch(()=>{reject()});
   });//also tried with bind(this)
 }
```

Using console.log(this.$BusinessService.getAllBusiness) in debug will show ƒ getAllBusiness() { ... the content of the code.

But hovering on it while debugging in chrome it will show undefined

Comment: Can you provide a sample GitHub repo that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with this line

```
.then((result)=>{
        this.appState.save('all_business', result.data);
        resolve()
      });
```

In this you are not returning. Try by returning result from the `then`.

Also `await` may need to be inside `async` function

Comment: I forgot to add await in my question. But it's there in the code. I'il edit to add. Ty for the notice. I also tried to await the then part and make the method async. It didn't change much. Also, executing the code i don't even enter the method. So I don't even hit that part for it to give me an error. Is it the way it's defined that would cause preproccessed js to fail define method?